# html5 input type date

Tags: html, date, input

I'm trying to change dat format on google chrome because my mysql request doesnot work using that format YYYY/MM//DD
is there a way to change this '/' by this '-' ?

I was looking on the internet several hours, but I did not find any way.

does anyone know how it is possible?

Kind regards.

SP

Comment: Chromium doesn't even show a special input for type `date`; but the format is defined via [the standard](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#concept-date), so I guess it is a bug, when using `/` instead of `-` as a separator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the HTML5 date field is called 'date' and gets passed through GET, the php code to change the date would be the following.

```
$dat = new DateTime($_GET['date']);
$new_format = $dat->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

That's it! Fairly simple, you then pass the $new_format variable as datetime to SQL.

Comment: ok so there is no way to display it as I want, because fromm internet explorer to google chrome using safari or others it display YYYY-MM-DD or YYYY/MM/DD so I don't know becaue it really depends on which browser you are

Comment: In fact I have something like that $sql = 'INSERT INTO factures SET
n_doss= "'.mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['n_doss']).'",
libelle= "'.mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['libelle']).'",
date_facture= "'.date('Ym-d',strtotime($_POST['date_facture'])).'",
date_echue= "'.date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['date_echue'])).'",
montant= "'.mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['montant']).'"
' ; And it does not change the format but it insert into my databse  01-01-1970

Comment: @StanislasPiotrowski You forgot a "-" in
date_facture= "'.date('Ym-d',strtotime($_POST['date_facture
Ym should probably me Y-m-d?And if you format as Y-m-d H:i:s it will do that for all browsers.

Comment: Oh I did not notice that previously. Thank you verry much for your help. I thought it was a problem of comptatibility between all browsers.